# Append DNS suffixes to /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: centos, dhcp

Is it possible, and how do I configure CentOS 6.6 so that /etc/resolv.conf will obtain its configuration via DHCP, but will also have additional domain names added to the search line?

Bonus points if I can also add a domain line to that file.

Oh, I don't use NetworkManager.

All searches so far have turned up instructions for disabling the modification of /etc/resolv.conf by DHCP, and manually setting it up, but I think this defeats the purpose of DHCP.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your `/etc/sysconfig/network` file, add:

```
DOMAIN=example.com
```

or

```
DOMAIN="example.com sub.example.com"
```

Settings in the file `/etc/sysconfig/network` apply to all network interfaces. Since all interfaces are usually part of the same domain, it is best to place the DOMAIN or SEARCH setting in this file. In the unusual case that the system has multiple interfaces, **and** the search domain is only valid for one of the interfaces, put the settings into the appropriate file for that interface, such as `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`.

The `domain` and `search` directives in `resolv.conf` are mutually exclusive. They've been going back and forth upstream on how exactly to handle it.  If `DOMAIN` doesn't work, try `SEARCH`.

Comment: I added `DOMAIN="foo bar baz"` to the end of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` and then did `sudo /etc/init.d/network restart` and the DNS domains where not added to `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Using `SEARCH` in `ifcfg-eth0` worked. `DOMAIN` did nothing. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that even minor Linux variants behave differently, so one of the options over there might work for other folks. https://superuser.com/questions/110808/how-can-i-add-additional-search-domains-to-the-resolv-conf-created-by-dhclient-i

Comment: Thank you very much!  "Settings in the file /etc/sysconfig/network apply to all network interfaces."  This is exactly the information I was looking for!

Comment: Adding `DOMAIN=...` to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts works` for Fedora28 and generates an entry `search ...` in `/etc/resolv.conf.